# Most efficient way of adding objects together

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if there is a quick way of adding attributes in objects together. If I had a 'Person' class like this and I was trying to add the 'age' attribute together from multiple 'Person' objects, then I could override the **add** function:

```
 class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.age + other.age
```

This works well for two objects, but if I had a list of 'Person' objects and I was trying to sum all the age attributes using the reduce() fuction for example, then this approach wouldn't work (to my knowledge), as the overriden **add** method would be trying to sum different types together as we are returning a float from the **add** function, not a 'Person' object.

I could get the age attribute from each 'Person' object and add it together but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of handling this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not logically make sense to add two people when what you want to add is their ages. Your problem is because if `p1 + p2` is a number, then `(p1 + p2) + p3` is a number plus a person, and you only defined how to add a person to a person, not add a person to a number.

But the root cause is that this is not a sensible case for overloading `__add__`. That only makes sense when the result would be another instance of the same class, not a number. Instead, just get the ages and add those. Note that this is **not** less efficient than operator overloading; it doesn't involve any attribute lookups that wouldn't have to be done either way.

```py
p1.age + p2.age

# or on a list:
sum(p.age for p in people)
```

*"Explicit is better than implicit."*

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you.